# Get filtered results from ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-textwatcher

How can I get a new `ArrayList<String>` of results after filtering an `ArrayAdapter<String>` using a `TextWatcher` in android?

The following is my code for filtering an `ArrayAdapter<String>` using the text from an `EditText` variable named `edtSearch`. The search function is working well. I need to put the filtered data into a new `ArrayList<String>`:

```
edtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to implement autocomplete?

Comment: I need a method to keep those obtained Strings into a new ArrayList

Comment: Show your filter method.

Comment: I used the built-in filter method from the ArrayAdapter<String>

Comment: Override it, then you will be able to do what your trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through your adapter and add the results remaining to a new `List`:

```
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
    results.add(adapter.getItem(i));
}
```